# Coldfusion 10 : jessionid not working when passed in url

Tags: session, coldfusion, jsessionid, coldfusion-10

We are migrating from ColdFusion 8 to 10. Our application is having functionality written in .NET as well however the session is maintained in ColdFusion only.

### Current architecture in ColdFusion 8 for .NET and CF integration:

1. Session is set when user logs in to the app (In CF). (We are using J2EE sessions.)
2. When a user clicks on a .NET link, `Jsessionid,CFID` and `CFTOKEN` are passed to .net page via url.  Inside .net code the following steps are done to check session:

   2a. Call a common function which will do a ColdFusion file request (chkSession.cfm) with `jsessionid` in url.

   2b. chkSession.cfm will return `session.UID` if available else will return -1. `Session.UID` will be available if the `jsessionid` in url is valid.

   2c. .NET page will be loaded if a valid UID is returned. User will be redirected to login page if -1 is returned.

### Issue in CF 10:

In CF 10 , always we are getting -1. I read that as part of security enhancement in CF 10, we will not be able to recreate a ColdFusion session by passing `cfide`, `cftoken`, `jsessionid` in the url.

I would like to get your advice on what is the best way to make our .NET functionalties work in ColdFusion 10. Is there any better way to check ColdFusion session from .NET ? 
One option I can think of is using a database. I looking forward to a solution that can be implemented quickly and is robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think would work would be to change your .Net client code to send over the JSessionID as a cookie value in its request. That way the functionality you have ought to work again.

It's worth noting that exposing the Session ID in URLs can expose you to certain security vulnerabilities, so it may be something you want to look at avoiding in future.

I have used the database approach you mention also. If you go this route, have the CF code insert a record using a GUID as an identifier and a timestamp for when the record was created. On the .Net side, look up the GUID and only accept the request if the timestamp is from less than X seconds ago, so you don't create a token which will authenticate you for a long time. X needs to be the max ammount of time you think it'll take a client to follow the redirect from CF to the .Net pages, so 2 is likely plenty.
You will want to delete used tokens and have a scheduled task to delete 'unused' tokens.

Comment: Thanks Barnyr. Im currently working on the cookie option. Will reply back with my findings soon. If that is not working then I will try out the DB option.

Comment: If you're not already, I recommend using Fiddler from fiddler2.com to debug your cookie code. You can use it to track how your browser presents the cookies and if you tell your .Net code to use Fiddler as the proxy then you can see what it's sending, which is invaluable when debugging HTTP requests

Comment: Hi Barnyr, The cookie logic worked like a charm ! We set JSESSIONID  as a cookie value in request and we were able to get the CF session details in .NET. Thanks for your support ! Cheers, Loshy

Comment: Hi Loshy. I'm late to the party here but just wanted to check how you ended up passing the cookie across in the request and whether this was initiated from the .NET app or the CF app or vice versa.